# How to get window (modal/nonmodal) such is "Find and replace"

Tags: vb.net

Can't find how to get new window (form) which will behave like "Find and replace" window in VB IDE 2008, where window is allways on top and I can work on it but I can also work with underlayed code bit find and replace don't hide when I set focus to code window.

The best solution will be if I would be oopen more than one such window.

This is how I try but opened window is modal!

```
Dim fl As New myWindow
With fl
    .StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    .aCallerLocation = Me.Location
End With

Dim ret As Integer = fl.ShowDialog(Me)
fl.Close()
fl = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the form as a dialog form, is not necessary to make the form stay in front of the primary form.  Using the `ShowDialog` method causes the form to be modal.  What makes it stay in front is the fact that you are passing `Me` for the `owner` parameter.  You can still pass an owner form, even if you are just calling the non-modal `Show` method:

```
Dim fl As New myWindow()
' ...
fl.Show(Me)
```

That way, the new form will stay in front of the primary form, but it will not be modal.  Therefore, both forms will be usable and you can show as many of those non-modal child forms in front of the primary form as you like.

Comment: That, of course works nice, thank you. In actual situation I have form to open which may have few different names. Is here a way from this code to forbid a form with same name (which is opened) to open again until it closes?

Comment: Yes, you could keep a reference to each form in separate form-level variables (private field of the form class).  You could have one variable per child form.  Then, when you want to show the form, you could simply re-show the same child-form object each time, rather than instantiating a new one each time.